# Access Shared Preferences from Different Activity (Android)

Tags: android, string, variables, preferences

When you establish a shared preference such as below...

```
public static final String PREFS_HI = "MyPrefsFile";
```

Can you access it from other activities just like you would normally do?

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_HI, 0);
```

Or is there something unique that you must do to access the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself. I just used global variables and stored sharedpreferences inside there. When another activity wanted to access the preferences, it would simple access a global variable.

Comment: You mean you have `SharedPreferences` stored as `public static`? You really should not be doing that. I made the same mistake and even though it works, it causes a huge memory leak. See: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 3):

I would store your shared preferences name (What you are calling PREFS_HI) in the resources xml file (strings.xml). Then you can just use `getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.sharedPrefs))`. Your solution works as well, though. (And the performance may be slightly better in your version.)

Comment: Ya, I looked into this alternative also.

Answer (score 0):

getApplication().getSharedPreferences(name, mode) try this